# Bug Repository for iPhone iPad apps

Tags: iphone, ios, repository, bug-reporting

Is there any opensource or public domain repository of bugs where one can see the bugs for ios app, for a particular app.

There are some for android, since it is open source, such as bug repository of Keepassdroid: http://code.google.com/p/keepassdroid/issues/

is there any for any popular iOS app?

Comment: I believe it is not publicly available since it is not open source...

Comment: Not sure whether it is helpful or not but check this out:https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/